# Truncate text in d3

Tags: text, d3.js, graph-visualization

I want to truncate text that is over a predefined limit in d3.

I'm not sure how to do it.

Here's what I have now:

```
  node.append("text")
  .attr("dx", 20)
  .attr("dy", ".20em")
  .text(function(d) { if(d.rating > 25) return d.name; }));
```

Text is only displayed if the rating > 25. How can truncate the text of those names?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To truncate text use `substring`

Try this code:

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/ZS48f/)**

```
 .text(function (d) {
     if(d.name.length > 5)
         return d.name.substring(0,5)+'...';
     else
         return d.name;                       
 });
```